# MySQL query to count occurrences on days of the year

Tags: mysql, date, group-by, count

I have a (large) table like this:

```
id     venue               city        date time
1      Waldorf Hotel       London      2020-01-01 07:00  
2      Waldorf Hotel       London      2020-01-02 07:00  
3      Heathrow            London      2020-01-02 14:00  
4      Lennon Airport      Liverpool   2020-01-02 16:00  
5      Port of Liverpool   Liverpool   2020-01-02 19:30  
6      Port of Liverpool   Liverpool   2020-01-03 07:00  
7      Port of Liverpool   Liverpool   2020-01-04 07:00  
8      Port of Liverpool   Liverpool   2020-01-05 07:00  
9      Port of Liverpool   Liverpool   2020-01-06 07:00  
10     Manchester Airport  Manchester  2020-01-06 12:40  
11     Heathrow            London      2020-01-06 14:40
```

So this person has been in Liverpool on 5 different days, in London on 3 different days, and in Manchester on 1 day only.

I am looking for a query that gets me this number of days that a certain city has been visited, resulting in this list:

```
    Liverpool      5
    London         3
    Manchester     1
```

But now I'm stuck at this query that counts the occurrences per day and I can't get it right:

```
    SELECT city, COUNT(city) AS value FROM visits WHERE YEAR(dt) = 2020 GROUP BY city, DATE(dt)
```

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for the comment. I'm getting output (so no error), but the result is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to select all the distinct city/date combinations in a subquery and then count the occurrence of each city:

```
SELECT city, COUNT(city) AS value 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT city, DATE(dt)
  FROM visits
  WHERE YEAR(dt) = 2020 
) v
GROUP BY city
```

Output:

```
city        value
Liverpool   5
London      3
Manchester  1
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22d67a/4)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! And so simple, I really need to use subqueries more often. Thanks.